# Calculating statistical odds of someone "liking" another person on a dating app based on known attributes and their prior "like" history?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to build a recommendation system that can estimate the probability of a person "liking" another user on a social media or dating app based on their previous "like history" and known attributes about each user.

One approach for this type of problem is to use a "collaborative filtering" mechanism as described [here](https://www.toptal.com/algorithms/predicting-likes-inside-a-simple-recommendation-engine), which uses the behaviour of other similar users to predict any other given user's behaviour.

However, in "content based recommendation", you would instead try to guess a user's future behaviour based on their prior "like"/"dislike" history and known attributes of the people they assessed. This is what I'm trying to find a mechanism for. An unrelated example is given [here](https://rubikscode.net/2020/04/20/guide-to-content-based-recommendation-systems/)

Let's say you have a given few known parameters for each user on the app that you want to base your prediction on (from user input or photo analysis). Hypothetically this could be for one individual user:

- photo estimated or inputted age (eg. 31)
- photo estimated gender (eg. 80% female, 20% male), or inputted gender (eg. female)
- photo estimated ethnicity breakdown (eg. 1% Asian, 1% Indian, 3% Black, 5% Middle Eastern, 5% Hispanic, 85% white) - could be simplified to 'dominant race' (eg. 'white') if needed
- inputted approximate user income (eg. $60,000)
- inputted height (eg. 170 cm)

Let's say then that user "Martha" has liked 10 other profiles and disliked 10 other profiles that were shown to her at random. Let's say you have the above data (or most of these fields) for these 20 profiles Martha has now judged.

What would be a simple mathematical approach to look at the degree to which any of these individual factors dictates Martha's like or dislike pattern? Or to assess then her probability of liking or disliking any new given individual's profile based on these variables?

For example, if Martha always likes guys who are taller than a certain height, and always dislikes guys below a certain height, we can probably guess this is a strong necessity in her mind and this may be a good predictor. Or if she only likes guys from 23-27 and dislikes all the ones outside that range. Or by contrast, if we see there is no obvious racial pattern perhaps that is less important.

Could we then apply a formula to a new user's parameters and guess her odds of liking them, or our confidence in guessing whether she might like or dislike them?

My thoughts are that at the start I would need to:

1. Establish the degree to which each variable is random in the user's prior like/dislike history. Ie. If the racial distribution of a user's likes/dislikes are similar, this is a random element which does not matter. If the height distribution of a user's prior likes/dislikes is very different, this is not random, and thus does matter.
2. Establish which variable values for the non-random variables are valuable (highly represented in the 'likes') or undesirable (highly represented in the 'dislikes').

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas. Perhaps there are many ways this could be done. I would appreciate any simple method or approach that could get me started.